# Symfony Routing Fallback Chain

Tags: symfony, routes

I'm use to Magento and the way that they chain their router responsibility to match for particular truths and return to the chain if a match is not found finally ending with the noRoute if the chain has not found an appropriate router for the request.

Is there a way to do this with Symfony?

Comment: Symfony2 requires lots of manual input for routing. I don't know how magento works, but this command: php app/console router:debug will tell you all your routes and this other command: php app/console router:match url will tell you which action matched the url.

Comment: Thank frances I was aware that i can supply exact matches and variable exact matches, i'm looking to basically do this

namespace_home_default:
    pattern:  /{controller}/
    defaults: { _controller: NamespaceHomeBundle:Default:index }


namespace_home_noroute:
    pattern:  /{controller}/
    defaults: { _controller: NamespaceHomeBundle:Default:noRoute }

and then in the default controller check to see if something is true, if not then the method that that should be used would be the noRoute.

I've figured out how to do this in one way which I will explain next.

Answer (score 0):

One way of accomplishing this is to for example:

```
#routing.yml
ajw_home_default:
    pattern:  /{path}/
    defaults: { _controller: AJWHomeBundle:Default:index }


ajw_home_noroute:
    pattern:  /{path}/
    defaults: { _controller: AJWHomeBundle:Default:noRoute }





    //default controller
public function indexAction($controller)
{
    //test logic to see if path exists
    if($path == 'test')
    {
      return 'something';
    }
    return $this->forward('NamespaceBundlename:Default:noRoute);

}



public function noRouteAction($data)
{
      throw $this->createNotFoundException('This Page Does Not Exist');//default symfony 404
      //return $this->render('NamespaceBundlename:Default:noRoute.html.twig');
}
```

I'm not sure that this is the best way to do this

For example I may look in the database to see if there is a blogpost with a stub = path

Comment: mmh I don't know how magento works so I can't really help I think. Anyway, you don't have do this in Symfony2. If a route doesn't match to any of the routes in any of your included routing.yml, it automatically creates a NotFoundHttpException. You don't have to control that on your controller. Routing does it for you.

Comment: And you can template yourself the "404 error page" page by overwriting twig bundle